# JavaFx 2.x : How to draw dashed or dotted lines?

Tags: line, draw, javafx-2

I would like to dynamically change the draw of a line from solid, dotted or dashed: it seems I have to use line.setStroke, is it the correct method?

And, how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: I have found a solution:by using this method
line.setStyle("-fx-stroke-dash-array: 2 12 12 2;");
I must using a refresh such as
pane.getChildren().remove(line);
pane.getChildren().add(line);
otherwise line do not turn to dashed from solid.(Windows XP).
Is there a different way other than this one? What's more, in Linux there is no need to use remove and add, it works correctly.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No that is not the correct method, setStroke sets the color of the stroke.
Correct method is `getStrokeDashArray().add()`:

```
Line line1 = new Line(20, 40, 270, 40);
line1.getStrokeDashArray().addAll(25d, 20d, 5d, 20d);

Line line2 = new Line(20, 60, 270, 60);
line2.getStrokeDashArray().addAll(50d, 40d);

Line line3 = new Line(20, 80, 270, 80);
line3.getStrokeDashArray().addAll(25d, 10d);

Line line4 = new Line(20, 100, 270, 100);
line4.getStrokeDashArray().addAll(2d);

Line line5 = new Line(20, 120, 270, 120);
line5.getStrokeDashArray().addAll(2d, 21d);

pane.getChildren().addAll(line1, line2, line3, line4, line5);
```

StrokeDashArray defines the pattern of line and gap sequences. See the following different patterns as output of aboves:

[image]

Of course by manipulating the StrokeDashArray array elements you can change the pattern dynamically.

Comment: I know this is old, but just to add, this does take a big hit on the performance, as every dash is drawn as its own line.

Comment: @Uluk I'm using this dashedArray(); `line.getStrokeDashArray().addAll(3d, 20d, 30d);` Why I'm getting this output? that is unexpected. http://imgur.com/a/DnzoV

Comment: what about `gc.setLineDashes` for dashed lines?